# Why is Spyder using libraries from base environment instead of virtual environment

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, spyder

I created and activated a virtual environment with virtualenv:

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

Then I installed spyder kernels and other libraries in the virtual environment:

```
pip install spyder-kernels==0.*
pip install numba==0.50
```

Then I launched Spyder in the virtual environment:

```
spyder
```

And I changed the python interpreter in Spyder to the correct path using: > Python > Preferences > Python interpreter > Use the following Python interpreter.

My Python interpreter in my virtual environment is

```
/Users/myname/venv/bin/python
```

I also restarted the Spyder console several times.

**However**, when I import libraries in Spyder, rather than the libraries installed in the virtual environment, Spyder uses the libraries from the base Anaconda environment.

```
import numba
print(numba.__version__)
0.38.0
print(numba.__file__)
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/__init__.py
```

This is causing all kinds of errors in my code.
What can I do to force Spyder to only use libraries installed in my virtual environment?

P.S: My Spyder version is 3.2.8, and Python is 3.6.6.

Comment: make sure you restart the kernel in Spyder after redefining the interpreter...launching Spyder from command line with environment activated, and my previous suggestion has caused me serious annoyance - but these two seemed to work for me usually

Comment: @DerekEden, I did that too, but I still experience the problem.

Comment: for shits, try launching the appropriate spyder from anaconda nav just to see, maybe it's still launching the base spyder from cmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the most recent version of Anaconda from [here](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), which came with Spyder 4.0.1 and Python 3.7.6. That alone solved the problem for me.